# Get intellisense on ` symbol in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

It is quite common to create a `template:` in your component in angalar2 .

just wondering if there is a way/extension that will make the string value which is html using the  **`** symbol to get html based intellisense in visual studio code?

ie.

```
@Component({
    selector:'my-puzzle'
    template:` <h2>foobar</h2> ` // get intellisense on this string
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in the current version of vscode. But you can upvote this idea on [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/9660111-html-editing-within-js-ts-code-e-g-in-es6-temp)
There is also a feature-request on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2000)